# how to make a fake post request using unittest module with cookies and data?

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint like this:-

```
@app.route('/name', methods=['POST'])
@limiter.limit("2000/day;300/hour;5/minute", key_func = get_uid_from_request)
@authenticate
def post(user):
```

How do I make a fake post request using unittest module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can make an *actual* post request

```
import requests

def test_post():
    resp = requests.post('http://localhost/name', 
                         data={'arg': 'value'}, 
                         cookies={'from-my': 'browser'})
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

I would recommend using [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) instead of unittest, but if you must use unittest

```
class TestPost(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_post(self):
        resp = requests.post('http://localhost/name')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: I am to make an http request as you said. But that's not how i want. I don't want to run the actual API and make http post request, rather i want to fake it using unittest module. I am doing like:- 

    `response = self.app.post('/name', data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.headers, cookie=self.cookie)`

The error it shows is,, TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cookie'

Comment: If you're not running the api, what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: The flask `test_client` doesn't accept `cookies` as a parameter.  I was using the `requests` library to make http requrests.  If you use the flask `test_client` you can set cookies on the client before you make the request -- `app.test_client().set_cookie(domain, cookie_name, cookie_value)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do like already suggested, and do an acceptance test against a running test instance with real post requests.

You can also check out Flasks documentation for testing at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/ which demonstrates how to do unit tests in which you can mock the incoming requests and test results.